# How jQuery's .on/.live works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

I was wondering how newly created element gets registered on jQuery's `.on/.live` function ?

How it was internally written in Javascript?

Are they call `addEventListener` on any document event which indicates that new element was created ?

I have seen the source code of `.live` , but I can't find anything in this regard.

Comment: Search for "event delegation"

Comment: @Bergi , Thanks, I found perfect answer here http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate